# Web scraping Reddit is not returning any values

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

respons = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(respons.text, "html.parser")

trend_news = soup.select("._3GfG_jvS9X-90Q_8zU4uCu _3Y1KnhioRYkYGb93uAKhBZ")

for news in trend_news:
    link = news.find("a")["href"]
    print(link)
```

I'm trying to get the links of the "trending news" on Reddit. However, when I run this script nothing happens, there's no output.

Comment: Hey @Abdullrauf Alhariri welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like Reddit has an API enpoint for [trending subreddits](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_api_trending_subreddits), which may be a better solution. If you want to continue with web scraping I would double check to make sure the string you're looking for in your select is something that remains the same between page refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. When using your CSS Selector `._3GfG_jvS9X-90Q_8zU4uCu _3Y1KnhioRYkYGb93uAKhBZ`, there should be a dot (`.`) instead of the space. So it would instead be `._3GfG_jvS9X-90Q_8zU4uCu._3Y1KnhioRYkYGb93uAKhBZ`.
2. The page gets loaded dynamically, therefore the `requests` module doesn't support it. (It won't matter even if you have fixed your CSS Selector).

You can get the data for "todays trending" via sending a `GET` request to their API `https://www.reddit.com/api/trending_searches_v1.json` that will return the data in the format of a python dictionary (`dict`), which you can access the `keys` / `values`.

```
import requests


# Add the user-agent header, otherwise, the page thinks that your a bot and will block you
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(
    "https://www.reddit.com/api/trending_searches_v1.json", headers=headers
).json()
```

```
>>> # You can access all data like a regular python dictionary
>>> print(type(response))
<class 'dict'>
```

For example, to access the titles:

```
...
for data in response["trending_searches"]:
    print(data["results"]["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["title"])
```

Output (currently):

```
Buttigieg promises 'infrastructure week' won't be a joke when he's transportation secretary
HBO Max now on the PlayStation 5
Mark Hunt vs Paul Gallen | 6-Rounds Boxing | Bankwest Stadium Australia
What fun in D2 dawning looks like
Line-ups Mashup for 7pm: Fulham vs Brighton, Liverpool vs Tottenham, West Ham vs Crystal Palace
[Roscher] Report: Russell Westbrook 'appalled' by Rockets team culture, which revolves around James Harden
```

Or, to access the links:

```
for data in response["trending_searches"]:
    print("https://reddit.com" + data["results"]["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["permalink"])
```

Comment: I'm just wondering about how did you get the API "trending_searches_v1.json"

Comment: @AbdullraufAlhariri In your browser open _developer tools (f12 in Chrome) -> Network__ when inspecting the network calls, you see that a request was made to that page